# Show the same date format on edit page

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Im storing the data with this format:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d F Y - H:i', $request->date);
```

In the database the date field is of type datatime.

Then in the edit page Im showing the stored data value like this:

```
value="{{ $rt->date }}
```

But its appearing also the seconds. Do you know how to show the same stored format?

Comment: Take a look at [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: You’ve probably got a few problems here. `d F Y - H:i` is not a valid MySQL datetime value, so what’s being saved in the database is probably wrong. Also, what is `$rt`? Where does that come from?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you check if whats stored in db is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
value="{{ $rt->date->format('d F Y - H:i') }}
```

To always get the exact format when fetching the `date`, you can add this to your model:

```
public function getDateAttribute($date)
{
    return $date->format('d F Y - H:i')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after add to the model that then to use how it is? {{getDataAttribute($rt->date)}} dont works!

Comment: after adding it to the model, you directly use `value="{{ $rt->date }}` in your blade

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears the seconds!

Comment: After adding the `getDateAttribute` method to you model, it will fix the issue

Comment: I add that method but it appears the seconds. It appears that the method getDateAttribute is not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Format the field when retriving

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($rt->date)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

or from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

```
public function getDateAttribute($value)
{
    return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On model you can set date format and force a field instance of Carbon

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';    

    /**
    * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at','date'];
}
```

And if you need change this format on blade

```
My flight date is {{$flight->date->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($rt->date)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

It convert date to 'd/m/Y' format. you can change format as per your requirements.